# How to extract keys from an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, list, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I have an array of tags

```
[
{"1boy": 0.9390615820884703},
{"solo": 0.9158311486244202},
{"male": 0.6592671275138855},
{"black hair": 0.4281844198703766},
]
```

How do I extract the string from this array of hashes so that they display as a list:

- 1boy
- solo
- male
- black hair

Comment: `.flat_map(&:keys) # => [:"1boy", :solo, :male, :"black hair"]`

Comment: You wrote "the string", but there is no string in your array of hashes.

Comment: Do you wish to extract the keys (as an array) or print them? If the former it's unnecessary and confusing to stipulate how they "display as a list" (especially with the bullets). Just ask how to create the array of  keys, period. If you want to display the keys in a particular format (with bullets, for example). ask for that. Because of the key-colon-value format you used in the hash, all keys are symbols. A symbol must be expressed as a quoted string following the colon only if the string contains spaces or does not begin with a letter. Here, for example, `"solo"`: can be written `solo:`.

Answer (score 0):

As SimpleLime posted in a comment, the most elegant way is using `flat_map`.

```
.flat_map(&:keys)
```

In your question you referred to the keys as "strings", but in your example, they are symbols. The syntax you are using for the hash is converting your "strings" to symbols.

```
"1boy": 0.9390615820884703
```

This makes a symbol for key that looks like a string, but is not. Ruby allow for creating symbols using strings, which is useful for creating symbols with characters that aren't typically allowed, such as punctuation or spaces.

```
:"some string?!".class
=> Symbol
```

If you truly want strings for the keys, you must use the "old" syntax with a `=>` operator:

```
"1boy" => 0.9390615820884703
```

So to return actual strings, you would also need to convert them. One possible way would be:

```
.flat_map(&:keys).map(&:to_s)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have nested structures or want just the keys of the first level:

```
.map{ |h| h.keys.first.to_s }
```

Comment: A better option would be `ary.map(&:keys).flatten` to include all keys and not just the first one.

Comment: I agree, but the best solution for this is `.flat_map(&:keys)`

Comment: `flat_map` does the same thing as `map().flatten`, only faster. https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/flat_map#1203-Alternative-definition